# laravel tables with relationship and insertion

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have 4 tables

- Customers : with data of customers. this table hasMany(Refunds)
- Refunds: with data of various request. this table belongsTo(Customers) AND belongsToMany(Services)
- Services: with list of services. this table belongsToMany(Refunds)
- Refunds-Services: bridge table for refunds and services

I have a form that must insert datas in the correct table.

```
public function storeRefunds(RefundsPost $request){

    DB::beginTransaction();
        $customers = Customers::create($request->all());

        $refunds = $customers->refunds()->create([
            'date_ref' => request('date_ref'),
            'status_ref' => request('stato'),
        ]);

        $tipo = $request->input('tipo', []);
        $importo = $request->input('importo', []);

        $refunds = Refunds::create($request->all());
        for ($i=0; $i < count($tipo); $i++) {
            if ($tipo[$i] != '') {

                $refunds->services()->attach($tipo[$i], [
                'services_id' => $tipo[$i],
                'services_amount' => $importo[$i]
                ]);
            }
        }

        return redirect("/");

}
```

with this code i can insert all datas in correct tables but i cannot find ID connection in the Refunds table. Two different ID are created in Refunds table. second created id in the Refunds table not connected to any customer (0) but connected to the list of services choosen.
How can i do?
Thx

Comment: Just remove `$refunds = Refunds::create($request->all());`. Run the code again & check for mapping.

Answer (score 0):

You need to debug your code. First `Refund` creates in this line `$refunds = $customers->refunds()->create` and it's belongs to `Customer`, second `Refund` creates here : `$refunds = Refunds::create($request->all());` and it's doesn't relate to any `Customer`, but relates to `Service` (you do this in `for` loop). By the way, your `tipo` input is not multiple (it should be with `[]` if you expects it can be more than one value) and `for` loop is senseless in this sutiation.

Delete one of `Refunds::create`methods, bring your data to expected view and use `createMany()` method.

More info in Laravel docs : https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method

Comment: my tipo is multiple because are the services can be added in one request of refunds

Comment: All data correctly stored in all tables but the only error is when it associates services to the request, it create a new request ID not connected to any customer

Comment: with one submition i have 2 id created in the refunds table first ID is correctly connected with the customer, but the second id is unusefull and it is connected to the various services selected. I mean the services selected are connected to the wrong unusefull second generate id in refunds

Comment: Maybe i cannot do this using Eloquent relationship, I had to pass manually the id?